# ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver On JAR Execution

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I see all related question about this problem, but i cant find my solution yet.

This is my `JAR` in class-path: (I use `NetBeans` IDE)

[image]

And this is `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 16.3-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: \UniversityProject\
Main-Class: Project.LoginFrame
[blank space]
```

I try run in command line:

[image]

I set java variables correctly:

[image]

Project settings:

[image]

Everything is OK, but where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the JAR to the classpath `Class-Path` entry in the manifest file

```
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
```

Comment: I add it, Same result

Comment: Did you match the exact name of the JAR?

Comment: Yes, i updated to this: `\UniversityProject\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`

Comment: My jdbc connector is `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin`, as you can see in the picture.

Comment: note the space between `UniversityProject` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`. Actually you can remove the directory name completely - this way you're not tied to that directory!

Comment: One another question: What if i need another `Jar` such as `joda` jar file? Where should i set in manifest ? `Joda` jar file is used in middle of my program.

Comment: Can i add more than one `JAR` on `CLASS-PATH` in manifest file?

Comment: Yep add it the same way - read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)